# Do the equations of motion simply tell us which degrees of freedom are superfluous?

Tags: field-theory, gauge-theory, maxwell-equations, dirac-equation, degrees-of-freedom

A massless spin $1$ particle in 4D has 2 degrees of freedom. However, we usually describe it using four-vectors, which have four components. Hence, somehow we must get rid of the superfluous degrees of freedom. This job is done by the Maxwell equations. To quote from Gilmore's *"Lie Groups, Physics, and Geometry"*

> “In some sense, Maxwell's equations were a historical accident. Had the discovery of quantum
>   mechanics preceded the unification of electricity and magnetism, Maxwell's equations might not have
>   loomed so large in the history physics. … Since the quantum description has only two independent
>   components associated with each four momentum, there are four dimensions worth of linear
>   combinations of the classical field components that do not describe physically allowed states, for each
>   four momentum. Some mechanism must be derived for annihilating these superpositions. This
>   mechanism is the set of equations discovered by Maxwell. In this sense, Maxwell's equations are an
>   expression of our ignorance.”

**Is there an analogous interpretation for the Dirac equation and possibly other equations of motion?**

Comment: Firstly, the author seems to be describing the role of Maxwell's equation for light--or "photons", in this context.  The classical analogue of photons are E&M waves which are solutions to the *vacuum* Maxwell equations, but the sourced equations describe also massive charges which surely have more than 2 degrees of freedom.  Secondly, the Dirac equation describes particles of ("fundamental") spin 1/2 which is a distinctly quantum phenomenon--unless your notion of "classical fields" extendeds to ones which cannot be represented by complex numbers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number)

Answer (score 1):

1. There are several things wrong/imprecise in the initial claims of the question about electromagnetism: In the Lagrangian formulation where the four-potential is the fundamental dynamical variable, the Maxwell equations are **not** equations of motion - only half of them are. The other half is just a consequence of $F=\mathrm{d}A$ and $\mathrm{d}^2 = 0$, and holds off-shell. Of all of Maxwell's equations, *only* Gauß' law represents a constraint related to gauge degrees of freedom. The other degree of freedom (the one also having to be eliminated for a massive vector field with three degrees of freedom) is eliminated by a constraint setting the timelike Hamiltonian canonical momentum to zero, which has nothing to do with Maxwell's equations (it's simply the almost trivial statement that $F^{00}  =0 $).
2. To answer the actual question: Dirac's equation is not an equation for a gauge theory, there are no gauge degrees of freedom to be eliminated. In general, it is *not the equations of motion that eliminate gauge degrees of freedom*. In the Lagrangian formalism, one has to introduce explicit auxiliary gauge fixing terms to eliminate them, which *would* admittedly lead to "equations of motion" that kill off the superfluous degrees of freedom. In the Hamiltonian formalism, the gauge degrees of freedom are eliminated by *constraints* incurred from the non-invertibility of the Legendre transform for gauge theory, cf. e.g. [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/351241/50583).

Answer (score 1):

The four polarisation degrees of freedom of the EM field correspond to the four DoFs of the charge-current vector. One is required for charge, two are for photon polarisation and the third is eliminated by the Lorenz relation, which corresponds to charge conservation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is: **Yes!**

Electromagnetic interactions are mediated by photons. Since a photon is massless it only has 2 physical degrees of freedom (there is no longitudinal polarization). Historically, electromagnetic interactions were described in terms of electric $\vec E$ and magnetic fields $\vec B$ or alternatively, in terms of the field strength tensor $F_{\mu \nu}$. Thus, in total 6 variables are used to describe only 2 physical degrees of freedom. Maxwell's equations are simply statements about the redundant components, similarly to how $x^2+y^2=r$ is a statement for the redundant variables $x$ and $y$ if we describe a two-dimensional rotationally symmetric system.

A nice discussion can be found at page 444ff in Spin in Particle Physics
by Elliot Leader

Comment: It would be much better if this answer *actually explained* why the answer is supposed to be yes instead of referring to a book.