# Are all solutions of Maxwell's equation related by a gauge transformation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, gauge-theory

Consider Maxwell's equation (without source):

$$ \partial_\mu F^{\mu \nu} = 0 \implies \partial_\mu \partial^\mu A^\nu = \partial_\mu \partial^\nu A^\mu.$$

Can we find a pair of classical field configurations $A^\mu(x),A'^\mu(x)$ such that they both satisfy the equation above (assuming similar boundary conditions) but are *not* related to each other by a gauge transformation of the type:

$$A'^\mu(x) = A^\mu(x)+\partial^\mu \varphi(x) \quad ?$$

If it's impossible, how could we argue/show this?

**Answer**: Thanks to my2cts' answer, I've found 2 solutions $A$ and $A'$ not related by a gauge transformation : $A^\mu=(0,e^{-i(t-y)},0,0)$ and $A'^\mu=(0,0,e^{-i(t-x)},0)$. It makes sense since they both give rise to different EM fields, which are invariant under gauge transformations.

Comment: I don't think one can answer this question until the boundary conditions are defined.

Comment: I think that reading the comments and answer to my question posed in the following link answer this question. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/452308/

Comment: @akhmeteli I completely agree and rarely if one ever sees them mentioned in the context of the vector potential but why?

Comment: Just for the record: there an even more trivial example. $A=0$ is a solution, the set of all solutions that differ from it by a gauge transformation are $A=\mathrm{d}\phi$. All such solutions have $F=0$. Clearly there exist solutions with non zero $F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there are many solutions that are unrelated by a gauge transformation, namely plane waves of any frequency, propagation direction, polarisation and phase  and superposition thereof.

Comment: @my2cts If I understand your point, the idea is that we can find 2 linearly independent solutions $E,B$ and $E',B'$ that solve Maxwell's equation, and since the EM fields are unaffected by a gauge transformation we cannot relate them to each other?

Comment: It is not obvious that all plane waves satisfy the same boundary condition, as I wrote in my comment, this depends on the boundary condition.